# An error occurred while running subprocess npm

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm

An error occurs when I try to start a new ionic project

I've tried to reinstall npm, node, ionic, clean npm cache
npm cache verify]
npm cache clean --force

**Error code:**

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
npm WARN deprecated debug@4.1.1: Debug versions >=3.2.0 <3.2.7 || >=4 <4.3.1 have a low-severity ReDos regression when used in a Node.js environment. It is recommended you upgrade to 3.2.7 or 4.3.1. (https://github.com/visionmedia/debug/issues/797)
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
npm ERR! Unexpected token : in JSON at position 260218 while parsing near '...RA9TVsSAnZWagAAGRgm":"d262c5b83aa5cf4386...'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Lucas\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-30T23_24_15_632Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm.cmd i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

**log:**

`4108 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.21370 4109 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "i" 4110 verbose node v14.16.1 4111 verbose npm  v6.14.12 4112 error Unexpected token : in JSON at position 260218 while parsing near '...RA9TVsSAnZWagAAGRgm":"d262c5b83aa5cf4386...' 4113 verbose exit [ 1, true ]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the answer right in the logs that you have posted.

```
npm WARN deprecated fsevents@1.2.13: fsevents 1 will break on node v14+ and could be using insecure binaries. Upgrade to fsevents 2.
```

And

```
verbose node v14.16.1 4111
```

Downgrade to a version of node less than 14 by either uninstalling your current version or using nvm. Personally I like [using nmv.](https://npm.github.io/installation-setup-docs/installing/using-a-node-version-manager.html)